# How does spark worker distributes load in cassandra cluster?

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, datastax, partition

I am trying to understand how cassandra and spark work together, especially when
the data is distributed across nodes.

I have cassandra+spark setup with two node cluster using DSE.

The schema is

```
CREATE KEYSPACE foo WITH replication = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor':1}

CREATE TABLE bar (
    customer text,
    start timestamp,
    offset bigint,
    data blob,
    PRIMARY KEY ((customer, start), offset)
)
```

I populated the table with huge set of test data. Later figured out the keys
that lie on different nodes with the help of "nodetool getendpoints" command.
For example in my case a particular customer data with date '2014-05-25' is on
node1 and '2014-05-26' is node2.

When I run the following query from spark shell, I see that spark worker on
node1 is running the task during mapPartitions stage.

```
csc.setKeyspace("foo")
val query = "SELECT cl_ap_mac_address FROM bar WHERE customer='test' AND start IN ('2014-05-25')"
val srdd = csc.sql(query)
srdd.count()
```

and for the following query, spark worker on node2 is running the task.

```
csc.setKeyspace("foo")
val query = "SELECT cl_ap_mac_address FROM bar WHERE customer='test' AND start IN ('2014-05-26')"
val srdd = csc.sql(query)
srdd.count()
```

But when I give both the dates only one node worker is getting utilized.

```
csc.setKeyspace("foo")
val query = "SELECT cl_ap_mac_address FROM bar WHERE customer='test' AND start IN ('2014-05-25', '2014-05-26')"
val srdd = csc.sql(query)
srdd.count()
```

I was thinking that this should use both the nodes in parallel during
mapPartitions stage. Am I missing something.

Comment: That is because of the replication_factor.A replication factor of 1 means that there is only one copy of each row on one node.

Comment: But the two dates are on different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to understand the interaction between spark and Cassandra as well as the data distribution in Cassandra.

Basically from spark application, request will be made to one of the Cassandra node, which acts as a coordinator for that particular client request.[More details](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/architecture/architectureClientRequestsAbout_c.html) can be found here.

Further [data partitioning and replication](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architectureDataDistributeAbout_c.html) will be take care by Cassandra system only.